# Bootstrap Mobile Phone Numeric Keyboard - Enter Event

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, keyboard

I have a problem about Bootstrap "number" input type in Android keyboard.

I want to show only numbers in mobile keyboard. So I use "number" type in input. But numeric keyboard in Android, "Next" button is not trigger to "Enter" event like normal keyboard "Next" button.

Is there anyway to trigger "Enter" event in numeric keyboard/input?

Comment: Post the code you have tried. Nobody is a mind reader here I don't think

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you want 'some' action to be performed when the enter/done key is hit on the numpad.

Here's a snippet of what I had used in one of my apps earlier, displayed the numpad when the input was tapped and action was performed when the user hit the done/enter key.

- Add  setOnEditorActionListener on the input field you have.
- Override the onEditorAction method and check if the actionId == IME_ACTION_DONE

  ```
    //Using the set edit listener to handle the events that occur when the Done/Search key is pressed
      userInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
              //When the search/done key is pressed
              if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
  // Do your action when Enter Key pressed
  }
  ```